# How to get root.plist to recognize types provided by InAppSettingsKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, plist, inappsettingskit

I'm having a hard time integrating InAppSettingsKit. First of all, XCode isn't recognizing that the `settings.bundle` I've added to my project actually contains files. So I have to open that bundle through the Finder to get at the `root.plist` file.

When i open it, the preference items are restricted to the basic types such as Group, Title, etc and if I try to use something provided by IASK such as `PSGroupIdentifier`, it immediately reverts to Group.

What am I missing here? What tells the plist file what types are allowable?

Answer (score 0):

First, to see the contents of Settings.bundle, click on it, and in the right pane (the inspector), set File Type to "Application Bundle".

As for Root.plist, these are items that are being used specifically in the Settings app, and as such are limited to a fixed number of options.  When you view it from inside XCode, you will see that when you create a new entry, there are only certain entries you can create.